# Should Twisted timeouts be cancelled when operation finishes successfully?

Tags: twisted

What is a recommended practice for handling a timeout that was set for a Twisted operation that finished successfully before the timeout expired?

Should the timeout be left running and depend on the `Deferred.cancel()` method having no effect on a finished Deferred?

Or is it better to explicitly cancel the timeout when the operation finishes?

The second option seems cleaner, but requires more complex and error-prone code (it is easy to leave a running timer, especially for operations that require several steps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the best thing would be to add a timeout-cancelling callback to the deferred in the same place where you set the timeout.

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor, task

def foo():
    return 'done'

def somethingPossiblyCanceled():
    return task.deferLater(reactor, 1, foo)

def addTimeout(d, duration):
    timeout = reactor.callLater(duration, d.cancel)
    def cancelTimeout(result):
        if timeout.active():
            timeout.cancel()
            print('(timeout canceled)')
        return result
    d.addBoth(cancelTimeout)

def main():
    d = somethingPossiblyCanceled()

    addTimeout(d, 2)

    def finished(result):
        print(result)
        reactor.stop()
    def canceled(failure):
        print('timed out: {0}'.format(failure))
        reactor.stop()
    d.addCallbacks(finished, canceled)

reactor.callWhenRunning(main)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Using deferLater here instead of callLater isn't doing yourself any favors here.  It's easier to use callLater to set up this call and easier to cancel it when that's necessary.

Comment: Jean-Paul Calderone: You're right, of course.  I've revised it.